# Filter on a literal column in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

with sqlalchemy, how would i filter on a literal column?

so i have a query, ex.

```
session.query(Object.att1, Object.att2, literal_column('x').label('xVar'))
```

now i want to to filter where the literal column != x.

the reason why i want to do that is because i have two queries that i combined in a union query, so each query has a literal column with and identifier which query it is.
and sometimes i have to filter the union query to return only one of the two queries.

Answer (score 0):

i think the answer is:

i need to set the query to a new subquery and then i could filter that query, as the following exemple.

```
unionQuery = session.query(Object.att1, Object.att2, literal_column('x').label('xVar')).subquery()
toFilter = session.query(unionQuery).filter(unionQuery.c.xVar!='x')
```